# Writing custom matchers that play nicely with Hamcrest AllOf / CombinableMatcher matchers

Tags: java, matcher, hamcrest

I am trying to compose two matchers, so that instead of writing

```
assertThat(response, hasStatusCode(OK));
assertThat(response, hasMessage("Some message."));
```

I can write something like

```
assertThat(response, 
    both(hasStatusCode(OK))
    .and(hasMessage("Some message.")));
```

However, I am getting undesirable strange output when running the assertion when one or both matchers fail:

```
Expected: (status code to be <200> and response to contain message "Some Message.")
 but: response to contain message "Some Message." response message was "Actual message"
```

where something seems to be interfering with the mismatch text. I would expect the 'but' line to read something like
    but: (status code was <200> and response message was "Actual message")

Logically, the matcher appears to work fine.

The matchers are:

```
private Matcher<Response> hasMessage(final String expectedMessage) {
  return new TypeSafeDiagnosingMatcher<Response>() {
    @Override
    protected boolean matchesSafely(final Response response, final Description mismatch) {
      String message = response.getEntity().toString();
      if (message != expectedMessage) {
        mismatch.appendText("response message was ").appendValue(message);
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void describeTo(final Description description) {
      description.appendText("response to contain message ").appendValue(expectedMessage);
    }

  };
}

private Matcher<Response> hasStatusCode(final Status expectedStatusCode) {
  return new TypeSafeDiagnosingMatcher<Response>() {
    @Override
    protected boolean matchesSafely(final Response response, final Description mismatch) {
      int statusCode = response.getStatus();
      if (expectedStatusCode.getStatusCode() != statusCode) {
        mismatch.appendText("status code was ").appendValue(statusCode);
      }
      return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void describeTo(final Description description) {
      description.appendText("status code to be ").appendValue(expectedStatusCode.getStatusCode());
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: It looks like your response has the wrong message. Have you debugged it? What message has your response?

Comment: How do you mean? The response contains "Actual message", while the matcher is expecting "Expected message" and so should (and does) fail. I've amended the post to include the expected output in the 'but' case. I also noticed that the assertion error message I pasted was for a slightly different test, so amended accordingly (OK == 200 not 202).

Answer (score 1):

That's just how `AllOf` presents a mismatch: it only shows the first `Matcher` to fail, with [its description followed by its description of the mismatch](https://github.com/hamcrest/JavaHamcrest/blob/5859a7504cd45664114539403861850a3dd7c1fb/hamcrest-core/src/main/java/org/hamcrest/core/AllOf.java#L26):

```
if (!matcher.matches(o)) {
    mismatch.appendDescriptionOf(matcher).appendText(" ");
    matcher.describeMismatch(o, mismatch);
    return false;
}
```

Given how the result will be generated, adding extra language like "didn't match because" to your mismatch message may make things clearer. An [open pull request](https://github.com/hamcrest/JavaHamcrest/pull/28) suggests a way that Hamcrest could make the description clearer, but that also has unclear edge cases.

See [Strange AllOf hamcrest matcher mismatch description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20566668/strange-allof-hamcrest-matcher-mismatch-description) for a similar question, around existing matchers rather than custom ones.